# Graphic visualisation ArborJS

Tags: arbor.js

I want to add graph visualisation to my php page and for that i have written code but I don't know why it is not showing anything. Can any one help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="arbor_files/jquery.js">       </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="arbor_files/arbor.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="arbor_files/arbor-tween.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="arbor_files/graphics.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="arbor_files/renderer.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="viewport" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(1000, 400,1);
sys.parameters({gravity:true});
sys.renderer = Renderer("#viewport") ;
var animals = sys.addNode('Animals',{'color':'red','shape':'dot','label':'Animals'});

var dog = sys.addNode('dog',{'color':'green','shape':'dot','label':'dog'});
var cat = sys.addNode('cat',{'color':'blue','shape':'dot','label':'cat'});

sys.addEdge(animals, dog);
sys.addEdge(animals, cat);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ported your code over and it loads fine.

[image: Animals Graph]

Can you check the location where you saved your js files?